# Error con npm install en linux

Tags: javascript, nodejs, linux, npm, gulp

He cambiado hoy a Garuda Linux y he querido pasar un proyecto que tenia en windows a este sistema operativo. Cuando paso el archivo package.json e intento hacer el npm isntall me sale el siguiente codigo:

He probado de todas las formas posibles que me salian en internet, borrando node_modules, borrando cache, reinstalando la ultima version de npm y node, creando el proyecto desde 0, todo, pero ninguna forma funciona, empiezo las clases dentro de 2 dias y tengo que solucionar este problema cuanto antes, muchisimas gracias por adelantado!

````
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated tar@2.2.2: This version of tar is no longer supported, and will not receive security updates. Please upgrade asap.
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /home/nacho/Escritorio/wilms/node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Building: /usr/bin/node /home/nacho/Escritorio/wilms/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '/usr/bin/node',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '/home/nacho/Escritorio/wilms/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.7.0 | linux | x64
npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (/home/nacho/Escritorio/wilms/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (/home/nacho/Escritorio/wilms/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (/home/nacho/Escritorio/wilms/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /home/nacho/Escritorio/wilms/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /home/nacho/Escritorio/wilms/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /home/nacho/Escritorio/wilms/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed  python2 Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (/home/nacho/Escritorio/wilms/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (/home/nacho/Escritorio/wilms/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (/home/nacho/Escritorio/wilms/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /home/nacho/Escritorio/wilms/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /home/nacho/Escritorio/wilms/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /home/nacho/Escritorio/wilms/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21) {
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed }
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` succeeded python /usr/bin/python
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: /usr/bin/python -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack                       ^
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:397:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:394:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1064:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:301:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Linux 5.13.12-zen1-1-zen
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/home/nacho/Escritorio/wilms/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /home/nacho/Escritorio/wilms/node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.7.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-08-21T12_57_42_356Z-debug.log ```
````

Comment: Primero lee las advertencias que da _NPM_, el paquete _urix_ está [obsoleto](https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated), por otra parte, los otros errores se pueden deber al primer punto, busca un paquete no obsoleto y después borra el caché de _NPM_ con `npm cache clean --force`.

Comment: Escribe en la consola `python --version`, ¿Cómo instalaste Node y Npm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error concreto que te está dando es debido a la falta de Python 2 en tu sistema:

```
...
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack                       ^
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax
...
```

Este es un error típico cuando intentas ejecutar un script de Python 2 utilizando el interpreter de Python 3 (Python 3 exige paréntesis para el comando print).

Sin embargo, en vez de instalar Python 2 (que ha dejado de recibir soporte en enero del 2020) me centraría en los paquetes que te están pidiendo Python 2, en concreto en `node-sass`. [Está marcado como obsoleto](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass) con la recomendación de pasar a Dart Sass. Quitando la dependencia de `node-sass` del `package.json` y ejecutando `npm install --save-dev sass` en la carpeta raíz de tu proyecto debería ser suficiente ya que exponen prácticamente la misma API.

Lo que no te puedo asegurar es si con eso queda todo resuelto. Si al intentarlo de nuevo te sigue dando errores mira con `npm outdated` si tienes más paquetes que necesitan actualización.

Espero haberte ayudado, aunque sea un poco. Suerte con las clases ;)